# Thunderbird losing window focus during email composition

Tags: email, thunderbird, focus

I've been using Thunderbird as my email client for a couple of years. Recently (in the last month or so), when I compose a new message, I have an issue. I start typing my message as normal. Then, at seemingly random times, the window loses focus. So I type a sentence, then look up to see what I've typed, only to find that it stopped typing several words before. This is deeply frustrating. It never used to happen.

I am running Windows 10 on my PC - Version 22H2 (OS build 19045.4046)  and Thunderbird 115.7.0 (32-bit).

I haven't installed anything new, but Windows update has run a few times recently.

If anybody has any idea how to fix this or what could cause it, I'd be very grateful for your help. If any more information is needed, please let me know and I will update the post.

Thank you :)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Do you know Which application gets the focus when it's lost? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'll do some testing and find out if something specifically takes the focus away. I normally just click back on the email window, so next time, I'll see if I can see where the focus has gone.

Comment: @harrymc - Thank you very much - I've now found the solution and posted it as an answer. Your help is much appreciated as it set me off on the path to find out what was going on.

Answer (score 1):

I've found out what it is - Thunderbird itself is causing the problem! If it auto-checks for new emails when I'm writing them, the email window loses focus to the main Thunderbird window. I found out when I had the main window open directly behind the email and at the exact moment I saw the blue line flash across the screen, my email window lost focus.

So the solution is to switch off the automatic check for new emails whilst I'm composing a message.

I know I'm answering my own question here - I just thought it might be useful to someone else if they have this issue.

Thank you to those who attempted to help me and especially harrymc who got me looking the right place :)

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand correctly that the "solution" is to lose auto-check ???
Note the problem is widespread: since TB 115, many background tasks that were only mentioned in the status line, now post a pop-up window, just to tell you "Fetching e-mail" or "Looking up certificates".
Please, TB team, what is the config variable to disable this annoying "innovation" ?